Creating a shell script to automate tasks
Everytime I log into my VM I need to:

sudo openvpn file.ovpn
python3 file.py
ifconfig
sudo docker-compose up

I want to create a shell script to automate this. I don't mind having to type the sudo password so I don't need to hard code it, I just want to run my .sh file and have everything happen.
The openvpn, python and docker lines all produce an ongoing process (as in when I run them in the terminal they don't just execute and then give me a @user where I can type more commands, but it ties up that particular terminal tab perpetually).
I tried using & on the end of each command but that didn't work. Can someone help me with getting this to run?

For 1), you should use --daemon e.g. sudo openvpn file.ovpn --daemon
For 2), consider using nohup. You can pipe the output to an output.log with nohup python3 file.py > output.log 2>&1 &
For 4), use detached flag docker-compose up -d (is sudo necessary?)

should not be a blocking process.

